# Custom malloc algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, function, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am currently working on a custom malloc function that either adds it regularly or to a best fit block. Meaning the block closest to the size. I am having trouble with the best fit part of the program. Here is the code in which I have:

I also have:

```
static  * First = NULL;
static  * Rover = NULL;
```

So in the best fit function I have a do while loop that goes around the circular linked list once. It is supposed to find the block that is the best fit for the memory the user is trying to malloc. Except it seg faults at:

```
if(best->size > Rover->size)
```

I think my logic makes sense but I dont undertand why im getting the seg fault.

In the very beginning of the function I declare best as:

```
 *best = NULL;
best = Rover;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why did you delete your code from the question? An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is basically always preferred above explaining your code in words.

Comment: On which platform the code should run? Is it for Windows or Unix?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize `best` to point to a dummy chunk with a size of zero.  To be sure you can test to see if `best` is NULL on your first run of the test your faulting on.  Assuming it is null then the fault is from dereferencing NULL in `best->size`

Or you could alternatively add a test for `best == NULL` before your size test.  If it is NULL  fall into the same `best = Rover`... code.  This is cleaner but has a slight performance impact due to the extra test.

Comment: So youre saying just make best->size = 0?

Comment: Kind of.  If best is pointing to null then you can't dereference it.  So you either have to not dereference (test if it's NULL first).  Or assign it to a dummy structure that has a size of 0 so you have something valid to compare to.

Comment: Okay I was able to get it! But now it is getting stuck in the while(1) loop below. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You need an exit condition.  While (1) says to loop forever.  Under what condition do you want to loop to end?

Comment: Okay like a break statement after the else?

Comment: Right.  Presumably inside the else clause.

Comment: Okay I dont seg fault anymore! Can I ask you if my logic looks correct for what im trying to do?

Comment: Rather than using a break though you're better off with- `while (bytes > (num_pages * PAGESIZE - sizeof(chunk_t)))`  then put the else clause after the while

Comment: Is there any code that runs before this but after your initialization?

Comment: Yeah theres a bunch of other functions but this part doesnt depend on all them

Comment: I'm assuming Rover gets set somewhere though?  What I really recommend is coming up with tests.  Set up some different scenarios and write tests around each of them.  Then run your code though and see what happens.  Testing can be a pain, but this is a great habit to get in to.  And nothing beats tests for giving you confidence your code is correct.